# WX: main window lost focus event

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to solve this basic use case: I have a main application window in `wxpython`, and want to fire an action (in this case, close the application), when the main window loses focus (i.e. when I click outside, and the window becomes inactive).

I've tried `EVT_KILL_FOCUS`, but it doesn't seem to work with the main window.

Right now I have this code:

```py
import wx

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    window = wx.Frame(None, title="Title", size=(800,600))
    window.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NullColour)
    window.Centre()

    def on_activate_evt(evt):
        if not evt.Active:
            window.Close()

    app.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE, on_activate_evt)

    window.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This works, but creates a problem: when I click on the top bar of the window, the EVT_ACTIVE gets triggered with status `evt.Active=False`, as if window decorations are not treated as part of the main window.

Is there any way to fix it (or some other way to achieve the desired behaviour)?

Comment: Add `style=wx.BORDER_NONE` to the Frame, then there is no `top bar` to click on.

Answer (score 1):

If you create some control which actually can take focus inside the frame, e.g. a `wxTextCtrl`, you would be able to catch `wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS` for it.

But I have to say that a window disappearing whenever you switch away from it looks likes a very strange UI decision. Perhaps you want to use something like `wxPopupWindow` instead?